# Is there a limit to the amount of data that can be passed on to the special output stream php://output?

Tags: php, csv, symfony1, http-headers

I'm currently testing out a new export to CSV feature for a report generated via a webapp. The relevant code looks thus:

```
$my_report_data = ReportDAO::runCampaignAnalysis($campaign_id, $start_date, $end_date);

$this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='export.csv');

$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");

function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
     $retval = fputcsv($filehandler, $tempArray);
     if($retval == FALSE) {
         error_log('Uh oh, spaghetti o!');
         error_log('The current line being processed is: ' . join('|', $vals));
     }
 }

 array_walk($my_report_data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
 fclose($outstream);

 return sfView::HEADER_ONLY;
```

$my_report_data is merely an multi-dimensional array of the form [seen here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#100033).

The code works perfectly with small datasets e.g. 100 rows and below (not quite sure where the cut-off is unfortunately). With larger datasets; however, rather than being presented with a File Open/Save dialog by my browser when I attempt to export to CSV, the raw report contents get displayed on the web page.

I've examined the HTTP headers with the 'Live HTTP Headers' plugin for Firefox and found that with larger datasets the headers aren't set properly and appear as 'text/html; charset=utf-8' rather than 'application/vnd.ms-excel'. Very bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

Odd: you might want to try flushing the output buffers periodically. I've found I need to do that to prevent similar errors. Something along the lines of:

```
if($len > 250){ $len = 0; if(ob_get_length()) ob_flush(); }
```

where `$len` is a count of lines. Messy to fit that into your `array_walk`, but that might help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Femi but like you pointed out it would be rather messy to fit it into my current solution. Not sure how flushing the buffers would fix the problem of the headers mysteriously reverting to 'text/html' either. FWIW though I did try that earlier without success.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a possible solution. Not entirely sure why it works; but it does. I merely added the following before the call to clearHttpHeaders:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

Worked like a charm.